# CONVERT_TIMEZONE issue in Greenplum

Tags: date, greenplum, datagrip

I have a query in Snowflake which I need to represent in Greenplum

So I am facing with that problem. These date functions don't exist in Greenplum:

`TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))`

How I can fix it in Greenplum?

Tried to find analogue functions

Comment: TO TIMESTAMP(TIMEZONE("UTC", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) also doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried `select to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP at time zone 'UTC', 'HH24:MI:SS')` or similar?